# NextJS | getStaticProps fails on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, react-apollo

### Describe the bug

I have a problem with `getStaticProps` and `Apollo GraphQL`. Part of website is supposed to be static pages. Data for pages is fetched with `GraphQL` from `Wordpress CMS`.

### To Reproduce

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch("https://wordpress/posts")
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id, slug: post.slug },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

```js
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const apolloClient = createApolloClient()
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: single_review_query,
    variables: { slug: params.slug },
  })

  const reviewBy = data.reviewBy

  return { props: { reviewBy } }
}
```

```
const Review = ({ reviewBy }) => {
  console.log(reviewBy )

  return (
    <Layout>
        // Content populated by {reviewBy} goes here
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

In the `getStaticPaths` of code I am getting all the `slugs` with `Wordpress REST API`. Then I am using those `slugs` in `getStaticProps` to fetch data.

### Expected behavior

The thing is that this code works while I am in `development` mode. Reviews are loaded as they should be and content is logged in `console` due `console.log(reviewBy)`. When I use `yarn build` problem occurs. I get this error in console

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/review/review-title-goes-here". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

It can't load title. Title is loaded with `reivewBy.title`. If I comment it out it will just throw error on next piece of code that loads data from `reviewBy` and so on, while it works as expected in `development`

### System information

- OS: Windows 10
- Version of Next.js: 9.4.0
- Version of Node.js: 12.16.3

### Additional context

REST API would be hard to implement in this stage of project so it would be greate if we could make `GraphQL` to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: During development, not every "getStaticProps" page is built. Maybe your getStaticPaths method also returns some posts that are invalid. Try catching and console logging posts that are `null` together w/ the slug and maybe you can find the culprits.

Comment: I am idiot. I loaded slugs from wrong url i wordpress. Damn. Thank you for making me think different :D